# Listar archivos y eliminarlos con find y rm

Tags: linux, búsquedas

He tratado de ejecutar este comando pero no logro que liste los archivos con cierta estructura con awk y después borre el resultado. En el siguiente caso los borra pero el archivo de salida lo genera sin información:

```
find /input1/input1/empleados/ -name "*" -type f -mtime +7 | \
      -not \( -path "*/auditoria/*" | \
      -o -path "/input1/input1/empleados/*.txt" \) | \
      -exec ls -lt {} \; | \
  awk '{FS=" "}{print $6"_"$7" "$8" "$9}' | \
  xargs rm -f > /tmp/Salida.txt
```

Comment: Para ser mas especifico, busca todos los archivos mayores a 7 dias, que excluya las rutas auditoria y los archivos .txt de empleados, que liste los archivos e imprima solo la fecha de creacion, la ruta donde se encuentra y el nombre del archivo, despues de esto que los elimine, pero que en el /tmp  guarde la salida de los archivos borrados

Answer (score 3):

Yo probaría de otra forma, no estoy seguro de que usar la salida de `ls` sea buena idea, facilmente se pueden crear problemas con nombres de archivos poco usuales.

Adicionalmente no creo que quieras la fecha de creación, quizás quieras la última fecha de modificación.

Para probar creé una estructura de archivos con los siguientes comandos y dentro de esa esctructura de archivos hice las pruebas:

```
mkdir -p test/{auditoria,empleados} && cd test
touch -d "8 days ago" {.,auditoria,empleados}/{1..5}{,.txt}
```

Primero asegúrate de que tu comando `find` hace lo que deseas. Busca en `man find` la opción `printf`, con ella puedes controlar la salida:

```
find $PWD -type f -mtime +7 -not \( -path "$PWD/auditoria/*" -o -path "$PWD/empleados/*.txt" \) -printf '%a %p\n'
```

Ahora observa que lo único que hacemos es ejecutar el comando `rm` con `-exec` y enviar el `stdout` que hemos controlado con `-printf`, para que nos muestre lo que nos interesa, a `tee`, que lo pasa de nuevo a `stdout` y al archivo `tmp`.

```
find $PWD -type f -mtime +7 -not \( -path "$PWD/auditoria/*" -o -path "$PWD/empleados/*.txt" \) -exec rm '{}' \+ -printf "%a %p\n" | tee tmp
```

**Importante**: Prueba los comandos en el directorio `test` que creamos al inicio y luego ajusta las rutas según tu caso particular, de lo contrario puedes terminar borrando más de lo que deseas y creo que ni stackoverflow ni sus usuarios asumen ninguna responsabilidad :).

Otra opción es usar un bucle lo que, a mi juicio, te das más control y claridad sobre lo que haces, en especial si luego tienes que hacer más trabajo sobre esos archivos.

Mi solución inicial con un `for` (que he dejado al final) no es buena idea pues al igual que la salida de `ls` va a traer problemas como menciona @fedorqui en su comentario.

Esta sería una forma correcta de leer find en un bucle, fíjate que usamos la opción `-print0` que usa el caracter `null` (`\0`) como separador en la salida en lugar de una nueva línea, que puede crear un resultado no deseado con algunos nombres de archivos:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do 
    stat $file --format="%y %n" | tee -a tmp
    #rm $file # ¿estás seguro de que vas a borrar lo que quieres borrar?
done < <(find $PWD -type f -mtime +7 -not \( -path "$PWD/auditoria/*" -o -path "$PWD/empleados/*.txt" \) -print0 2>/dev/null)
```

Enviamos el `stderr` de `find` a `/dev/null` por si hay errores de lectura de archivos.

Descomenta el comando `rm` para eliminar los archivos.

Revisa el comando `stat`, la opción `--format` (o `-c`) con `%n` y `%y` te dan el nombre del archivo y la última fecha de modificación legible para humanos.

Esta era la solución inicial usando un for, que es un buen ejemplo de lo que no se debe hacer:

```
for file in $(find $PWD -type f -mtime +7 -not \( -path "$PWD/auditoria/*" -o -path "$PWD/empleados/*.txt" \) 2>/dev/null);do
    stat $file --format="%y %n" | tee -a tmp
    #rm $file # ¿estás seguro de que vas a borrar lo que quieres borrar?
done
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Mi única objección es tu tratamiento del `for` con `find`: `for file in $(find ...)` es muy frágil y falla en casos tan básicos como que el nombre del fichero contenga espacios. Largamente explicado en [How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612232/1983854), la mejor solución parece  `find ... | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' ...`.

Comment: @fedorqui Totalmente correcto tu comentario, he editado la respuesta para dejar la opción con la redirección como la opción a usar. ¡Gracias!

Comment: De todos modos, sigues indicando `for file in $(find ...` como opción, cuando la de `find ... | while ...` parece más indicada. Ah, muy bien comentado lo de no parsear `ls`, siempre es interesante leer [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/40596).

Comment: @fedorqui he incorporado el uso de `find ... | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'` en lugar del `for` en la respuesta como la forma adecuada de usar find en un bucle.

Comment: Fantástica labor didáctica, ¡ojalá te veamos mucho aquí en [es.so]!

Answer (score -2):

`find /input1/input1/empleados/  -type f -mtime +7 -not ( -path "/auditoria/" -o -path "/input1/input1/empleados/.txt" ) -exec ls -lt {} \; | awk '{FS=" "}{print $6"_"$7" "$8" "$9}'| xargs -I[] rm -f '[]'`

Comment: Tienes que dejar una explicación sobre cuáles fueron tus cambios en el comando, y lo que te llevó a pensar la respuesta. Cómo es que el código soluciona el problema y cuestiones como esa. Si lo dejas así, no se entiende lo que quieres responder.